# FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 104139 in Flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

I am using google map in flutter android app. I got accidentally crashed my app on pressing back button or to next screen.
Please have a look in this error message.

```
W/libEGL  (21050): EGLNativeWindowType 0x9f9cd808 disconnect failed
E/AndroidRuntime(21050): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 104139
E/AndroidRuntime(21050): Process: com.example.app, PID: 21050
E/AndroidRuntime(21050): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.y.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):16)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):8)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bz.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):29)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):151)
E/AndroidRuntime(21050):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@221514063@22.15.14 (100306-0):48)
E/BufferQueueProducer(21050): [SurfaceTexture-0-21050-16] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
W/libEGL  (21050): EGLNativeWindowType 0xc2e384c8 disconnect failed
I/Process (21050): Sending signal. PID: 21050 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: I was using a polylines list, on back press or on forwarding if that list were empty app suddenly crashed and this error was generated in the console. Now I use loader until the array is empty. And this is working for now.

Comment: Hi, did U get any solution? I have the same problem: E/AndroidRuntime(12163): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
E/AndroidRuntime(12163):  at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(12163):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222116097@22.21.16 (190400-0):2)

Comment: set a default start and end point until the current location is not captured. And if you are drawing polyline, then set a condition to draw the polyline after the current location is fetched or use those default start and end points to draw polylines until the current location is fetched.

Comment: Thx. I don't enable to show user location on the map, I don't need that feature.